# Track deleted user in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to track which user was deleted from SQL Server and when was it deleted?

Comment: Do you mean user as in Database User? Or user as in SQL/Windows Logon? They're different things.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about detecting when new Server Logins are created and dropped, yes you can do that with server-wide DDL triggers. For example:

```sql
drop trigger if exists DDL_Server_Logins on all server;
go
create trigger DDL_Server_Logins
on all server
for create_login, drop_login
as
begin
    declare @event_type sysname, @command nvarchar(max)
    select @event_type = eventdata().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]','nvarchar(128)'),
        @command = eventdata().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');
    print 'Server Cat is watching (' + @event_type + '): ' + @command;
end
go
create login doobey with password = N'Doobey Doobey Doo!';
go
drop login doobey;
go
drop trigger DDL_Server_Logins on all server;
go
```

Which outputs the following:

```
Server Cat is watching (CREATE_LOGIN): create login doobey with password = N'******';
Server Cat is watching (DROP_LOGIN): drop login doobey;
```

Notes:

1. It's up to you to record where and when this happens, such as in audit tables.
2. It's not retrospective - the trigger has to exist (and remain enabled) to capture these events in real time.

References:

- [CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql)
- [Use the EVENTDATA Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-eventdata-function)
- [DDL Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-events)

Answer (score 1):

If you have got audit setup already using any of the below means, you will be able to see when user was deleted.

- Profiler trace
- Server level triggers
- Extended events
- Monitoring tools
- any other auditing means

If you don't have any audit setup already, if you are having regular backups, you can find out, which users were deleted, between backups.